# How to cast integer to binary in mariadb

Tags: sql-server, mariadb

I have trouble with cast function in mariadb. With the same query but result in sql server and mariadb are difference.

In sql server:

```
Query: select CAST(1234 as binary(10))
Result: 0x000000000000000004D2
```

In mariadb:

```
Query: select CAST(1234 as binary(10))
Result: 1234
```

I don't understand it. Please help me explain and suggest solution.

Comment: I would suggest googling what binary actually means in mariadb (it's a string data type in mariadb), and use something like hex() for your needs.

Comment: Thanks @ZLK. Your suggestion sloved this problem.  The hex() can help in this case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`binary` is a character type, but there is `hex` function to get the hexadecimal value of a expression.

```
select hex(1234);
+-----------+
| hex(1234) |
+-----------+
| 4D2       |
+-----------+
```

If you want the same format it can be done using other functions:

```
select concat('0x', lpad(hex(1234),20,'0')) ;
+--------------------------------------+
| concat('0x', lpad(hex(1234),16,'0')) |
+--------------------------------------+
| 0x000000000000000004D2               |
+--------------------------------------+
```